# Understanding the Step of Solving Separable Equations

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a question about the following algorithm:

[image]

My concern is boxed in red. Why is $u$ replaced with $y$? Because they are equal functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable $u$ in the integral 
$$\int \frac{1}{h(u)} \textrm{d}u$$ 
is called a dummy integration variable. It acts to tell the reader what variable we are integrating the function $1/h$ against. A possibly simpler way to see this is through the change of variable $u=y$ in the above integral.

Calling the dummy variable $u$ or $y$ doesn't change the meaning of the integral, as long as we are consistent about which variable is actually the integration variable. For example, if we were to compute
$$ \int f(x) \textrm{d} z, $$
we would notice that the function $f(x)$ is constant as a function of $z$: regardless of what $z$ value we chose, $f(x)$ doesn't change, so the above integral becomes
$$f(x) \int 1 \textrm{d}z  = f(x)z+C, $$
which is clearly different from
$$\int f(z)\textrm{d}z = F(z) +C \ \textrm{for} \ F'(x) = f(x).$$

As an aside, the use of a dummy variable becomes much more important if the function $h$ depends on $y(t)$ and also a parameter $\mu$, so the differential equation reads $$\frac{1}{h(y(t),\mu)} \frac{\textrm{d} y(t)}{\textrm{dt}} = g(t).$$

Now, we would expect the solution of the differential equation to also dependent on the value of the parameter $\mu$. The same series of steps to solve the separable ODE leads to
$$\int \frac{1}{h(u,\mu)} \textrm{d}u = \int g(t) \textrm{d}t. $$
Now, however, the integral on the left hand side is a function of $\mu$, and the solution of the ODE will be as well-just as we expected. The use of the dummy variable $u$ here makes it clear that we are not integrating $h(u,\mu) $ with respect to $u$.